# Riccati equation – uniqueness and blow-up

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the Riccati equation as the initial value problem

\begin{equation}
y'(x) = a \, y(x) - b \, y(x)^2 \; , \quad y(x_0) = y_0 \; ,
\end{equation}

with constant coefficients $a, b > 0$. By the Picard–Lindelöf theorem there exists a unique solution in some rectangle

\begin{equation}
[x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta] \times [y_0 - \epsilon, y_0 + \epsilon] \; ,
\end{equation}

with $\delta, \epsilon > 0$.

I can construct a solution to the above IVP,

\begin{equation}
y(x) = \frac{\textrm{e}^{a (x - x_0)} \, y_0}{1 + \frac{b}{a} \, y_0 \left[ \textrm{e}^{a (x - x_0)} - 1 \right]} \; ,
\end{equation}

which blows up at $x = x_0 + x_*(y_0)$ with

\begin{equation}
x_*(y_0) = \frac{1}{a} \, \ln \left( 1 - \frac{a}{b \, y_0} \right) \; ,
\end{equation}

provided that $1 > a/(b y_0)$.

That is, for $y_0 > 0$ there is (possibly) a blow-up at some $x < x_0$ and for $y_0 < 0$ there is (definitely) a blow-up at some $x > x_0$.

Now I am wondering, whether it is true that for any $y_0 > 0$ the constructed solution is unique in the interval

\begin{equation}
(x_0 - \lvert x_*(y_0) \rvert, \infty ) \; ,
\end{equation}

whereas for any $y_0 < 0$ the constructed solution is unique in the interval

\begin{equation}
(- \infty , x_0 + x_*(y_0)) \; ,
\end{equation}

and how to see that?

Comment: Yeah, after the blowup time, the solution seems to remain unique due to the fact that it is the unique solution of the equation that blows-up at $x_0+x_*(y_0)$. So in some sense, on the other side of the blowup, the position of the blow up plays the role of the initial condition.